# Sum the return values of multiple functions in another function and print it. to console

Tags: python

Hi I'm having trouble summing the return values of multiple functions in another function. I really have no idea how to do this. I have an idea of what to do but nothing seems to work. My sum() function is missing something to connect all the functions together. Please help me understand this.

```
def function1():
    #Asking user for score earned on assignment, max score is 100
    scoreEarned = int(input("Score earned? "))
    return scoreEarned


def function2():
    #Asking user for score earned on assignment, max score is 100
    scoreEarned = int(input("Score earned? "))
    return scoreEarned


def function3():
    #Asking user for score earned on assignment, max score is 100
    scoreEarned = int(input("Score earned? "))
    return scoreEarned


def sum():

    sum1 = function1()
    sum2 = function2()
    sum3 = function3()
    #finalSum = sum(sum1,sum2,sum3) this was an idea
    print(sum3)

def main():

    function1()
    function2()
    function3()
    sum()

main()
```

Comment: `print(sum(function1(), function2(), function3()))`

Comment: Isn't it just a question of how to do a sum in python? Also please don't use internal keywords as names. Eg: `sum` is an internal keyword.

Comment: do not define a function with the name `sum` - it is a built in function

Comment: You function are absolutely identical - why create 3 of them . create 1 and call it three times

Answer (score 1):

your `sum` function overwrites the built-in `sum` function. calling the `sum` function inside of your `sum function` will call itself and, because your `sum` function does not accept any arguments, will raise an Error.

change the name of your sum function (or create a hook for the built-in sum function and call that) to fix this issue.

Edit:
you are asking the user for input 6 times (3x in `main` and 3x in `sum`. you can remove the calls in `main` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

sum takes an array as an argument,to make it work with you'r code you can try this

```
def sum():
    ar = []
    ar.append(function1())
    ar.append(function2())
    ar.append(function3())
    sum = sum(ar)
    print(sum)
return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the functions for user input twice once in main and once in the sum function.

You can simply call them in main and pass the values are parameters of sum, and return the sum from the sum function:

```
def sum(val1, val2, val3):
     return val1+val2+val3
val1 = function1()
val2 = func......
sum = sum(val1,val2,...)
```

or you can simply call the sum function and remove the extra calls from main, and sum the values in the sum function:

```
def sum():
    return function1()+function2()+function3()
def main():
    sum()
```